# Custom EventHandler in Xamarin.Forms doesn't work in xaml

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In `Xamarin.Forms`, in PCL, I have custom control, with custom event:

```
public class TestGrid : Grid
{
    public EventHandler OnTapped;

    public TestGrid()
    {
        var tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 1 };
        tgr.Tapped += Tgr_Tapped;
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);
    }

    private void Tgr_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnTapped?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

in my StartPage I have:

```
public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
{
    public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new StartPageViewModel();
        MainGrid.OnTapped += OnGridTapped;
    }

    private void OnGridTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Tapped!");
    }
}
```

My XAML looks like that, and it works:

```
<v:TestGrid x:Name="MainGrid" />
```

**BUT!**

when I remove `MainGrid.OnTapped += OnGridTapped;`
and add event in xaml, here:

```
<v:TestGrid x:Name="MainGrid" OnTapped="OnGridTapped">
```

I doens't work. It says.. OnTapped event not found:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 6:33. No Property of
>   name OnTapped found

My question is: **Why?** What's the difference?

Comment: the OnTapped you declared in code is not a *property* - it doesn't have a getter/setter.  It's just class level variable.

Comment: Adding getter and setter and making it a property didn't work:/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`OnTapped` must be an event:

```
public event EventHandler OnTapped;
```