# Accessing name when toggling switch in listview xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the below codes which consist of a list view. The listview contains a label and a custom switch.

```
 <ListView x:Name="myListView" Margin="20" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell IsEnabled="False">
                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"  />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <local:CustomSwitch x:Name="customSwitch"  
                                     SwitchOffColor="Gray"  
                                     SwitchOnColor="Red"  
                                     SwitchThumbColor="White"
                                     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  
                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                     Grid.Column="1"
                                     />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

What I want to achieve is to get the label text when I toggle the switch. How can In achieve this in Xamarin Forms from my ViewModel ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to create a Bindable property in your CustomSwitch like

```
BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(object), null);

public object CommandParameter
{
    get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty ); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(CommandParameterProperty , value);
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml adapt your declaration to

```
<local:CustomSwitch x:Name="customSwitch"  
       SwitchOffColor="Gray"  
       SwitchOnColor="Red"  
       SwitchThumbColor="White"
       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       Grid.Column="1"
       CommandParameter={Binding .}
       />
```

Now in your codebehind you can easily access and consume the CommandParameter and cast it to string:

```
string labelName = (string) ((sender as CustomSwitch).CommandParameter);
```

Comment: How can I add an event handler to trigger when I toggle the switch ?
`Toggled` does not seem to work.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848585/custom-eventhandler-in-xamarin-forms-doesnt-work-in-xaml